# Set doNotStrip packagingOptions to a specific buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

My project has 3 different buildTypes and I need only one of them to keep the debug info of its native libraries. I'm using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4`.

I tried the following

```
buildTypes {

   debug {
   ...
   }

   release {
   ...
   }

   unstripped {
       ...
       packagingOptions {
           doNotStrip '**/*.so'
       } 
   }
}
```

but that makes all buildTypes to keep unstripped versions of the libraries.

I also tried changing the `doNotStrip` pattern to something like `'**/unstripped/*.so'` but that does not seem to help me, since the [docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.1/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html) say that the path is related to the APK's root dir.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this doesn't work?

Comment: Poked at it some more, and it seems like a gradle bug or atleast an issue with how `packagingOptions` is implemented. The settings seem to be global and not scoped to particular variants.

Comment: I opened a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215248

Comment: Hi, @tmm1. No, I haven't been working with Android for a while now, so I ended up not looking further into it. Thanks for opening the report! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version [7.0.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/JniLibsPackagingOptions#keepDebugSymbols:kotlin.collections.MutableSet) the use case is supported with a new syntax. [Example](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215248#comment5):

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("debug")) {
        packaging.jniLibs.keepDebugSymbols.add("**/debugDoNotStrip.so")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the `build.gradle` file should the `androidComponents` be specified?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a workaround for you:

**Feeding a command line option "`doNotStrip`"**

1. Add below to your `app/build.gradle`

   ```
   android {
       ...
       if (project.hasProperty("doNotStrip")) {
           packagingOptions {
               doNotStrip '**/*.so'
           }
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Use below command to generate the **unstripped apk** by feeding option `doNotStrip` to the command.

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleUnstripped -PdoNotStrip
   ```
3. For other build types, you can still use the normal build commands. e.g.

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleDebug
   ```

   or

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleRelease
   ```

   but don't feed option `doNotStrip` to the command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's almost exactly what I ended up doing, actually... But, is it possible to do something as simple as I tried to initially? If it's impossible, could you explain me why? I'm new to Gradle and it would be nice to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

[`doNotStrip` function is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions), please use [`keepDebugSymbols`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/variant/JniLibsPackaging#keepDebugSymbols()) instead.

build.gradle.kts:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
        debug {
            packaging.jniLibs.keepDebugSymbols.add("**/*.so")
        }
    }
}
```

It works for me.