# How to override defaultConfig abiFilters in buildTypes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

`abiFilters` is set in android `build.gradle` defaultConfig block.

I'd like to exclude `x86` from release buildType, but can't find an easy way to do it

Here is the `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        moduleName "cipher_v1"
        cFlags "-DRELEASE=1"
        if (rootProject.ext.has("testCrack")) {
            cFlags += " -DTEST_CRACK"
        }
        if (project.ext.has("authKey") && project.ext.has("androidId")) {
            cFlags += "-DAUTH_KEY=\\\"" + project.ext.authKey + "\\\""
            "-DANDROID_ID=\\\"" + project.ext.androidId + "\\\""
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
   release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
unzip -l base-release.aar|grep cipher
17752  02-01-1980 00:00   jni/armeabi/libcipher_v1.so
17640  02-01-1980 00:00   jni/x86/libcipher_v1.so
```

Here is what I really want:

```
unzip -l base-release.aar|grep cipher
17752  02-01-1980 00:00   jni/armeabi/libcipher_v1.so
```

**I'd like to keep a full `abiFilters` in the `defautlConfig` block**

**And specify ones in certain `buildType`**

---

EDIT 1:

Yes, removing the `defaultConfig` and setting `abiFilters` in both `debug` & `release` block would work. But my question is how to utilize the `defaultConfig`

Comment: Answered my own question, but willing to see if any better solutions. Still don't know how to completely override abiFilters from defaultConfig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feeding a command line option, e.g. "**no_x86**"

1. Add below to your `app/build.gradle`

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       ndk {

           ...
           if (project.hasProperty("no_x86")) {
               abiFilters "armeabi"
           } else {
               abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
           }

           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use below command to generate the APKs without **x86** ABI by feeding option `no_x86` to the command.

   ```
   ./gradlew assemble -Pno_x86
   ```

   but don't feed option `no_x86` to the command if you want to build APKs **with** x86 abi. As the `defaultConfig` is to keep a full abiFilters per your requirement.

   For certain **buildType**, you can invoke the corresponding build command by feeding or not feeding the `-Pno_x86` property. E.g. `./gradlew assembleRelease -Pno_x86`

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980193/8034839

Comment: Well done workaround. The override `default`/`flavor`/`buildType` properties in `build.gradle` itself is annoying, but it is simple for outside caller.

Answer (score 2):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
            }
        }
        release {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`productFlavors` also would support dimension `abi`.

Comment: This would work, but I want to maintain a default abiFilters in defautConfig. And only tweak some of the buildTypes or flavors

Comment: @Felix.D when only configuring build-type `release`, it might require a `reset()`. this at least works with `splits`, where one could even build two separete packages. as the issue is being described, it sounds alike as if `abiFilters` would only add filters, but not override them, as expected.

Comment: it's exactly the opposite approach, but when `defaultConfig` would only have `armeabi` configured and build-type `debug` would then add `x86`, this might work out.

Comment: Thanks, your comment lead me to a solution

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Martin, I found a workable solution from this:

`when defaultConfig would only have armeabi configured and build-type debug would then add x86, this might work out`

I realize that `adding wanted abi to debug` is a workaround for `removing unwanted abi for release`

**Works For Me**

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
      //abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        abiFilters "armeabi"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        ndk {
          //abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
    }
    release {
        //ndk {
        //    abiFilters "armeabi"
        //}
   }
}
```